# Get google analytics data via dart / flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

What is the best option to get google analytics data in a flutter app?
I'm a new beginner in app development.
My app should show some analytics data and some graphics (I'll use a chart library).

What is the easiest way to get google analytics data?

Comment: You can use a Flutter plugin to use the Google Analytics for Firebase API:
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics

Comment: I want to access google analytics data of an analytics account that already does exist. It has nothing to do with Firebase.  I just want to get all google analytics data of a specific analytics account and show the data in a diagram.

Comment: In this case you have to use Google Analytics API.

Comment: the whole OAuth 2.0 mechanism doesn't seem to work or at least I'm too dump to implement it right.  Is there a good tutorial for this? 
Why do I need to use OAuth 2.0?  Why can't I just use a simple API Key to authenticate?  
I just need google analytics data of one account.

Comment: do you mean Google Analytics API or Google Analytics Reporting API?

Comment: With Google Analytics API you can get data from Google Analytics.

Comment: Hello @TomBerry. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, there's no plugin available for Flutter to be able to fetching Google Analytics Data. However, [Google Analytics Data](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) can be fetched using REST API. You can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest) for more details.